# Problem with Grid inside the GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I am trying to put table in the form of `Grid` into `GraphicsGrid`. Here is my code:

```
sinfunc[ampl_, freq_, phase_, x_] := ampl Sin[2. Pi freq x + phase];
A1 = 1.;
A2 = 0.5;
f1 = 2.;
f2 = 5.;
phase1 = Pi/4.;
phase2 = Pi/3.;
plotstyle = {Blue, Red};
padding = {{25, 5}, {15, 5}};

plot = Plot[{sinfunc[A1, f1, phase1, x], 
    sinfunc[A2, f2, phase2, x]}, {x, 0., 2. Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0., 2. Pi}, {-1., 1.}}, AxesOrigin -> {0., -1.}, 
   PlotStyle -> plotstyle, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> padding];
emptyplot = 
  Plot[{}, {x, 0., 2. Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0., 2. Pi}, {-1., 1.}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0., -1.}, PlotStyle -> plotstyle, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.]], 
   ImagePadding -> padding];

legendSin1 = 
  LineLegend[{plotstyle[[1]]}, {""}, LabelStyle -> {0}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {25, 5}];
legendSin2 = 
  LineLegend[{plotstyle[[2]]}, {""}, LabelStyle -> {0}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {25, 5}];

size = 12;
text = Partition[
   Style[#, size] & /@ {"", "Sin1", "Sin2", "", "", "", "Frequency", 
     ToString[f1], ToString[f2], "Amplitude", ToString[A1], 
     ToString[A2], "Phase", ToString[Round[phase1, 0.01]], 
     ToString[Round[phase2, 0.01]]}, 3];
table = Grid[text,
  Dividers -> {All, {1 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True, 5 -> True, 
     6 -> True}},
  Alignment -> {Center, Center, {{3, 5}, {2, 3}} -> Left},
  Spacings -> {1, 1.2}
  , Frame -> {None, 
    None, {{3, 5}, {2, 3}} -> Directive[(*Thickness[2]*)Thickness[0.005], Black]}
  ];

grid = GraphicsGrid[{{emptyplot, plot}}, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[table, Scaled[{0.1, 0.5}]], 
    Inset[legendSin1, Scaled[{0.15, 0.63}]], 
    Inset[legendSin2, Scaled[{0.255, 0.63}]]}]
```

When I save the `grid` as PDF (`Export["Grid.pdf", grid]`). I get following image:

[image]

(Please notice that I am interested in PDF format of image, here I put JPG format due to format upload restrictions.)

I am facing <s>two</s> **one problem**:

1. LineLegends `legendSin1` and `legendSin2` are missing in the PDF. However, they are present in the Mathematica notebook view of `GraphicsGrid` grid.
2. <s>The table (`Grid`) appears as black rectangle. This in fact might be somehow related to the option `Frame`. If the `Frame` is commented out, the table appears normally.</s> @MelaGo solved this problem by changing the thickness of `Frame` to e.g. `Thickness[0.005]` instead of `Thickness[2]`.

I am using 12.1 version of Mathematica. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: The black box is due to `Thickness[2]` - lines are so wide they fill up the grid. Try `Thickness[.02]`

Comment: @MelaGo Thank you! It solved my second problem. I edited my question.

Comment: Your code works fine in Mathematica 12.2 with windows 10 (`LineLegends` exist in pdf).

Comment: @BenyIzd You are right. I asked my colleague to run it on Mathematica 12.2 and I can confirm that `LineLegends` exist in pdf. I am using the 12.1 and they are missing in pdf. I wonder if somebody else can confirm this on 12.1.

Comment: Version 12.1 seems to have some problems exporting to `pdf`, there was [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242152/problem-with-special-characters-when-exporting-to-pdf) similar issue with the same version.