# Exporting plots containing special characters using MMA 13.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: bugs, export

Is there any way to export plots as pdfs correctly on Ubuntu?

An example of the problem:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, AxesLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", "#"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "characters don't export well: \[Gamma] \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[CapitalOmega]\), \(mn\)]\)."]
Export["exampleExportBugPDF.pdf", %];
```

Produces:

[image]

Is there any work-around? If that is not possible, what is the closest way to export plots such that they looked good when zoomed in.

There are previous questions on this subject such as [Problem with special characters when exporting to pdf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242152/problem-with-special-characters-when-exporting-to-pdf) but they were apparently fixed in 12.2. Now in 13.2 I have same symptoms.

Other suggestions such as below don't change anything:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}];

SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["TraditionalForm"], 
      PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]}]];
```

Exporting as .eps has the same artifacts.

---

"13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 7, 2022)"

Comment: Using `13.2.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2023)` installed on Ubuntu on Windows, I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: There is a [recent similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/pdf-export-is-heavily-flawed-for-simplest-possible-notebook-such-as-a-bc/) on this topic (with one hackery solution). Also, this looks like a very clear bug, and I strongly suggest you report it to [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: @LukasLang, Thanks I will look whether it is possible for me to upgrade again.

Comment: @Domen, yes I was actually thinking that a performing the export on the Cloud might help. I have a slightly different applications though (single plot vs document) so I don't think this is a duplicate. Also I prefer programmatic solutions if possible. I imagine it might be possible to do the export on the cloud programmatically but I am not that familiar with those functionalities.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Fedora 37 using 13.2.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023).